# Debian 7.5 Prevents Access to Router, Hardware is OK

Tags: networking, ssh, router, debian, sshfs

My Problem:  I can't access my router from the Problem OS (Debian 7.5) of my main computer.  I am sure the hardware is okay.  It would be problematic to reinstall the Problem OS.

Problem OS Symptoms and Details:  When I try to access the internet with IceWeasel (FireFox), Icedove (Thunderbird), GoogleEarth, Tor, Windows 7 virtual machine, nothing happens, or I get a DNS lookup failed, or Server not Found message.  Ping from the Problem OS to the Router or DSL modem returns "connect: Network is unreachable".  Other than these symptoms the Problem OS works just fine.

How I Know My Hardware is Okay:  The laptop I am writing this post on uses the same router / DSL modem as the Problem OS, and accesses the 'net and pings the router and DSL modem just fine. Two live systems (TAILS on a USB stick, Debian 7.5 on a CD) both work on the computer with the Problem OS to access the 'net.  A fresh install of Debian 7.5 on a different drive of the same computer with the Problem OS also accesses the net just fine. While I have not tried Ping on every working OS above, I have tried it on both the laptop and the newly installed Debian 7.5 and it works fine.  I also switched the cables around and found no cable problems.

What I Did to My Software to Cause the Problem:  I had a LEGO EV3 Brick attached to the Problem OS.  I had just installed ev3dev and gfortran on the micro sd card of the brick (ev3dev is based on a Debian 7.5 fork).  Everything seemed just fine at that point.  I tried to move a file from the Problem OS to the Brick.  I tried the scp command to move the file with no luck.  There were error codes along the lines of source file not recognized.  I may have had the wrong path or wrong syntax, or may have lacked the correct underlying configuration.  I installed sshfs, and tried to establish a shared folder.  The Problem OS stopped accessing the internet, and I thought my DSL modem might have had a problem, but found out otherwise after rebooting the modem and router and then brought out this computer.

My Background:  I am new to Linux.  I have been using it for less than a year now.  I know enough to cause the current problem, but not enough to fix it.  I might be dangerous when put in a room with a finely tuned computer.

What I Have Done:  I reinstalled the non free network drivers from the Debian site, which worked in the past, and on the spare HDD Debian 7.5 install with no change in functionality.  I have tried to find a modified file from the time of Problem OS failure but was stymied by the huge numbers of files changed and no clue as to which file / directory to check in.  I did a complete removal of sshfs and also reinstalled it.

A Possible Clue to What is Wrong:  In Terminal, when I try to ssh into the Brick via Ethernet over USB, I am prompted to enter the password for root of the Brick.  The root PW for the Brick does not work.  I then enter the root PW for the Problem OS, and somehow I am then logged into the root account of my Problem OS, and I can't access the Brick like I had been able to do.

What I Think is Wrong:  I think I have a single line of a single configuration file wrong, and the problem was caused by a random error on attempting the scp command, or more likely the sshfs command.

Comment: What does your `/etc/network/interfaces` file say?

Comment: /etc/network/interfaces (omitting comments) Line 1: auto lo Line 2:  iface lo inet loopback

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem.  In the process of loading and initially configuring Debian Wheezy on to the LEGO EV3, I had to establish an ethernet link over USB.  That necessitated altering the IPv4 config which I did in Debian 7.5 desktop by 
System Settings > Network> choose the wired connection to the LEGO brick (the other wired connection is the ethernet connection) > IPv4 tab > change "Method" from "Automatic (DHCP)" to "Shared to other computers".

There are other steps in this process outlined on the ev3dev page on Github.  The problem is the two wired connections share this change, and when the system is rebooted, the ethernet connection comes up as "Shared to other computers" which will not work with the router or dsl modem.  Which explains the other OS's working fine on the problem computer.

Unfortunately, I did not discover this before I reloaded the operating system and all the other software I use.  So, I can't be absolutely sure this is the problem, as the old OS is gone at this point.

As I see it, there are three ways to proceed from here:

1. Every time I reboot after having paired the LEGO EV3, reconfigure the IPv4 tab either manually or with a script,
2. Get a wireless ethernet dongle for the LEGO EV3, and network to the brick in the usual fashion, or
3. some alternative means of networking involving simultaneous conventional ethernet and ethernet over USB which does not cause changes to one to affect the other.

I chose the ethernet dongle method, but would prefer dual network mode as I view WiFi as an unnecessary security hole.  If anyone knows what to do or where to point me, I am all ears.